# How do I query for a calendar event's reminders? Future events show up but their reminders do not

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, android-calendar

When I query the content resolver for Events.CONTENT_URI, it correctly shows me future events and that they have an alarm. But when I query for Reminders.CONTENT_URI, it only shows me reminders that have occurred already. I want to find if a future event has a reminder and allow the user to remove it if needed. How do I do this? Where do I find that info?

**Only reminders that have already occurred are showing up here**

```
//Get all reminders
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
    Reminders.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null 
);

//None of my future events show here even though they have reminders
while (cursor.moveToNext())
{           
        Log.d(TAG,
                "Id: " + cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Reminders._ID)) +
                ", Minutes: " + cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Reminders.MINUTES)) +
                ", Method: " + cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Reminders.METHOD))
        );
}
```

**This shows all future events (all of which have reminders, but they don't show in Reminders**

```
//Get all events
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
    Events.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null
);

while (cursor.moveToNext())
{           
     //This correctly shows the future events each have an alarm (hasAlarm = 1)
     Log.d(TAG, 
          cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Events.TITLE)) + ","
          cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Events.HAS_ALARM))
     );
}
```

How do I find (and also alter) the reminders for future events?

**EDIT: CalendarAlerts also does not show alarms for future events! The future events are not showing up in CalendarAlerts.CONTENT_URI**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the eventid as arguments in the query of future event for which you want Reminders
`args = new String[] { Long.toString(mEventId) };` and also need to use where clause `private static final String REMINDERS_WHERE = Reminders.EVENT_ID + "=?";`

Comment: Thanks! So telling it specific events you want must make it go beyond the cache sqlite db and query the provider, correct?

Comment: Yes , if you want the code look at Calendar code http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.1.1_r1/com/android/calendar/EventInfoFragment.java . In this class look for the 'TOKEN_QUERY_REMINDERS'